# Highcharts: useHTML flag not working when rendering labels

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I am using highcharts and a phantomjs server to render charts and labels but the useHTML flag while rendering the labels does not seem to be working. I started the server as mentioned in the docs 
*phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 3003*

and then I am sending post requests with the following as the infile

```
{
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var label = this.renderer.label('Hello  &nbsp;&nbsp;  World', useHTML=true)
            .css({
                    color: '#FF11FF',
                    fontSize: '12px'
                })
            .attr({
                    fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.75)',
                    padding: 8,
                    r: 5,
                    zIndex: 6
                })
            .add()

            box = label.getBBox();
            label.align(Highcharts.extend(box, {
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 20
                }),
                null, 'spacingBox');

            var label2 = this.renderer.label('Goodbye World')
                .css({
                    color: '#222222'
                })
                .add()
            label2.align(Highcharts.extend(label2.getBBox(), {
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 0,
                    y: box.height + 40
                }),
                null, 'spacingBox');
        }

    },
    height: 800,
    width: 500
},
title: {
    text: ''
}
};
```

I am then exporting this as an svg, but the text for the label gets printed as it is. I also tried

```
var label = this.renderer.label('Hello  &nbsp;&nbsp;  World',null, null, 'rect', null, null, true)
```

but this leads to the first text not being displayed at all, the blue background gets added and so does the second text but not the first text. The first one is not even working on export.highcharts.com but the second one works fine over there. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Renderer.label takes more arguments than you provided, docs:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.label

Example:

```
this.renderer.label('Hello  &nbsp;&nbsp;  World',null,null,null,null,null,true)
```

Your fiddle with proper use of Renderer.label:
https://jsfiddle.net/6atnc2xj/